# Spring boot recover from readiness or liveness states

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, amazon-s3, readinessprobe

I am experimenting with K8s and the spring boot liveness and readiness probes. One thing I cannot seem to understand and fix properly is how is my spring boot application supposed to recover from a failed state? I have a simple scenario - my app is connecting to an S3 bucket and tries to download the content. And I want to make sure that the when the bucket is not available, then my Readiness state is automatically changed to `REFUSING_TRAFFIC`. But then when the bucket is up and available again, I want my Readiness state to be updated again to `ACCEPTING_TRAFIC`.

How do I do that?

Here is what I have:

```
@Slf4j
public class AcpS3EnvironmentRepository extends AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository
        implements EnvironmentRepository, SearchPathLocator, InitializingBean {
    
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONFIG_VERSION = "latest";
    private final AcpS3TransferManager transferManager;
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;
    
    public AcpS3EnvironmentRepository(ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
            AcpS3RepositoryProperties properties,
            AcpS3TransferManager transferManager,
                                      ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        super(environment, properties);
        this.transferManager = transferManager;
        this.eventPublisher = publisher;
    }
    
    @Override
    public synchronized void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.state(getUri() != null, "You need to configure a uri for the aws s3 bucket");
    }
    
    @Override
    public synchronized Locations getLocations(String application, String profile, String label) {
        try {            
            transferManager.downloadBucket(new AmazonS3URI(getUri()).getBucket(), getBasedir().toPath());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Could not load data from bucket " + getUri(), ex);
            AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(eventPublisher, this, ReadinessState.REFUSING_TRAFFIC);
            throw new AcpS3BucketIllegalException("Could not load data from bucket " + getUri());
        }
        return new Locations(
                application,
                profile,
                label,
                DEFAULT_CONFIG_VERSION,
                getSearchLocations(
                        getWorkingDirectory(),
                        application,
                        profile,
                        label
                )
        );
    }
}
```

What I observe currently:

1. Make s3 not working
2. readiness is refusing_traffic
3. s3 is working again
4. readiness is still refusing_traffic (but it should be accepting traffic this time).

So my question is how do I achieve this in the best possible way?

Comment: Only solutions (until quantum entanglement better researched;): Or s3 has to tell, (your app/publisher) Or your app has to "poll"!

Comment: s3 can invoke lambda function, when bucket (content) changes..

Comment: Yeah but the bucket is not in my "hands" and I have to rely on my spring boot service only. The AWS S3 library has also a method `doesBucketExistV2` so I can check this from time to time and set the Readiness state to a correct state, but I am not sure if this is a good idea.